Issues Generating .ism and .ismc Files from .ismv with ffmpeg on Windows
I'm attempting to generate .ism and .ismc files for a .ismv file using ffmpeg on Windows. However, when I run the command:
ffmpeg.exe ismindex -n myvideo myvideo.ismv

I consistently encounter the following errors:

[AVFormatContext @ 00000281781fef40] Unable to choose an output format
for 'ismindex'; use a standard extension for the filename or specify
the format manually.  [out#0 @ 000002817822a780] Error initializing
the muxer for ismindex: Invalid argument Error opening output file
ismindex.  Error opening output files: Invalid argument

I've checked the documentation and various forums for a solution but haven't found anything that resolves these issues. Could someone please guide me on how to correctly generate the .ism and .ismc files using ffmpeg on Windows?

I discovered that the ismindex command cannot be used directly in the FFmpeg command line. Instead, it needs to be compiled as a separate tool.
You can download the FFmpeg tools for Windows from this website.
